# SQL Find Holes in Linear Time-Based Table

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a linear datetime based table in MySQL and SQL server for a time-based data collection system.  There is required to be a new entry in this table that will be timestamped exactly every 10 seconds.  Sometimes, the data collection source goes down for a while and comes back up, at which point the newest data is inserted into the table, and a new thread is spawned to start back-filling in the "holes".

Is there a SQL statement I could use to find the last "hole" in the ten second values so that I would know where to start asking for backup data?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd guess that you will need to use a different queries for MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for SQL Server, try something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    DATEADD(second,-10,t1.YourDateColumn)
    FROM YourTable t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM YourTable t2 
                          WHERE DATEADD(second,-10,t1.YourDateColumn) = t2.YourDateColumn)
    ORDER BY t1.YourDateColumn DESC
```

Comment: Great thanks, I think that basically works.  Here is your query for MySQL:

SELECT * FROM source1 t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM source1 t2 WHERE t2.sample_time = addtime(t1.sample_time, sec_to_time(10)));